# Sorting in xslt

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I keep trying to use xsl: sort and having no luck.  Here is my xsl.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="no" method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mountain">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="name[@language='English']"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="height"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name[@language='English']">
        Name: <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="height">
        Height: <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- -->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Asg10.xsl"?>
<FamousMountains>
  <mountain>
    <name language="English">Mount Everest</name>
    <name language="PigLatin">ountMa verestEa</name>
    <location>Nepal</location>
    <height units="feet">29035</height>
  </mountain>
  <mountain>
    <name language="English">Mount Ranier</name>
    <location>Washington</location>
    <height units="feet">14411</height>
  </mountain>
  <mountain>
    <name language="English">Mount St. Helens</name>
    <location>Washington</location>
    <height units="feet">8364</height>
  </mountain>
  <mountain>
    <name language="English">Mount Washington</name>
    <name language="PigLatin">ountMa ashingtonWa</name>
    <location>New Hampshire</location>
    <height units="feet">6288</height>
  </mountain>
  <mountain>
    <name language="English">Mount Bonnell</name>
    <name language="PigLatin">ountMa onnellBa</name>
    <location>Austin</location>
    <height units="feet">800</height>
  </mountain>
  <mountain>
    <name language="English">Mount Vesuvius</name>
    <name language="PigLatin">ountMa esuviusVa</name>
    <location>Italy</location>
    <height units="feet">4203</height>
  </mountain>
  <mountain>
    <name language="English">Mount Etna</name>
    <name language="PigLatin">ountMa tnaEa</name>
    <location>Sicily</location>
    <height units="feet">10922</height>
  </mountain>
</FamousMountains>
```

I am trying to sort Mountains by height in a descending order, like this.

> Name: Mount Everest
>   Height: 29035
>   Name: Mount Ranier
>   Height: 14411
>   Name: Mount Etna
>   Height: 10922
>   Name: Mount St. Helens
>   Height: 8364
>   Name: Mount Washington
>   Height: 6288
>   Name: Mount Vesuvius
>   Height: 4203
>   Name: Mount Bonnell
>   Height: 800

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I ook out the xsl sort as it kept breaking my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort the **mountain** elements by height, you will be need to have an explicit **xsl:apply-templates** to select the **mountain** elements, combined with an **xsl:sort** command to specify the sort parameters.

Try adding the following template, which should do the trick

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="mountain">
        <xsl:sort select="height" data-type="number" order="descending" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

As an aside, you don't actually need the template that matches `/` in this case, as this is only really doing what XSLT's built-in template will do anyway without it.

Comment: Thanks, I just butchered the template when  I tried it seems. Much appreciated.